# Python - how to merge (append) text files without iterating line by line

Tags: python, file-io

Is there a quick way to copy one file's content to another one, without iterating the file line by line and writing to the other file?

Answer (score -1):

```
from subprocess import call
call(['cat', 'readfile.txt', '>>', 'writefile.txt'])
```

Comment: This tells `cat` to output the concatenation of files named `readfile.txt`, `>>`, and `writefile.txt`. `cat` doesn't process `>>` the way you're relying on; that's the shell's job.